# Unable to run the cronjob in ubuntu 10.10 server, EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a AWS EC2 instance with ubuntu 10.10 server.
I am trying to add a cron job to the list. But the cron job is not being executed.

I am actually uploading a particular file to aws s3 using s3cmd visit s3tools.org

What will be in the problem and also the solution.

Kindly help me out

Here is the bash script which has to be run

```
s3cmd put file-name s3://bucket_name/foder_name/file-name
```

Here is the job

```
bash /path/to/file.sh
```

Comment: Do you have a running `/usr/bin/cron` process?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch yes I have added the job to crontab

Comment: Please add the contents of your crontab (and what it calls) here. There might be an error on line 42.

Comment: @wildplasser i have added more informations kindly have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware that the global crontab (/etc/crontab) has a user field:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
```

While the crontab of a user (reachable by running crontab -e as a user) does not?

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

This drove me crazy once: cron was failing relatively silently...

That said, try and make a very simple cron entry, maybe directly inline, that touches a file in a writeable folder. This way you'll figure out if it's your script or cron that's being difficult.

Comment: I just observed the logs its actually executing the script but I am not able to see the results. I mean the files are not being uploaded to the S3

Comment: So your cron is fine, it's the script that's problematic. Make sure you have the right paths in there, cron doesn't run with the same environment variables you'd get in a normal shell

Answer (score 0):

- Is cron running? you can test this by adding *to your crontab*:

  * * * * * /bin/date >/tmp/the_time
- is my crontab being called? You can test this by adding *to your cronscript*:

  echo "Hello world!" >/tmp/the_hello
- Does my cronscript get the right path-settings when it is invoked?: add *to your cronscript*:

  set >/tmp/the_settings

In most cases the scripts that are called from cron need to have most of their pathnames hardcoded, sometimes even PATH needs to be set or expanded.

Answer (score 0):

was able to figure out the solution for this. The problem was I need to specify absolute path thats /usr/local/bin/s3cmd .